# Set a div width, align div center and text align left

Tags: html, css

I have a small problem but I can't get it solved. 
I have a content header of 864px width, a background image repeated-y and footer image.
Now I have this `<div>` over the background image and I want it to be like 855px width and the text align left but yet aligned center so it fits in the bg.

I once had it oke width some padding left but I figured out that was the correct padding for my screen resolution.

Soo briefly it is:
Setting a div width - align the div center - align its text (content) left.

Answer (score 40):

Set auto margins on the inner div:

```
<div id="header" style="width:864px;">
    <div id="centered" style="margin: 0 auto; width:855px;"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, text align center the parent, and force text align left on the inner div:

```
<div id="header" style="width:864px;text-align: center;">
    <div id="centered" style="text-align: left; width:855px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Try:

```
#your_div_id {
  width: 855px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: This pretty much done the trick! Text align had to be left and done.

Only now.... The text crosses the background lines of the content. Tried solving it with some padding but it wont budge...

Comment: Just be sure to have the divs semantic ordered.

<div id="content"> <!-- properly styled with width -->
  <div id="your_div_id">
    [text content]
  </div>
</div>

Answer (score 12):

Use auto margins.

```
div {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: NNNpx;

   /* NOTE: Only works for non-floated block elements */
   display: block;
   float: none;
}
```

Further reading at [SimpleBits CSS Centering 101](http://vault.simplebits.com/notebook/2004/09/08/centering/)

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers should suffice.
However if you don't have a defined width, auto margins will not work.

I have found this nifty little trick to centre some of the more stubborn elements (Particularly images).

```
.div {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
   margin-right: 0;
}
```